# ActivityComponent and SingletonComponent relations together in hilt module class

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

I have some binds or provides relations for ActivityComponent and some for SingletonComponent in one Hilt Module class .... how could i achieve that?

Example:

```
@Module
@InstallIn({ActivityComponent.class, SingletonComponent.class})
public absrtact class MyHiltModule {
   @Binds
   @SomeQualifier
   abstract SomeInterface bindSomething(SomeImpl someimpl); =======> for activity scoped lifecycle
   

   @Binds
   @AnotherQualifier
   abstract SomeInterface binsAnotherThing(AnotherImpl anotherImpl); ===> for application scope lifecycle
}
```

Comment: It's impossible. Anything installed from a higher-level component cannot be removed from a lower-level component. If you want to inject multiple instances of the same type, you must use a qualifier.

Comment: @bambam you are right updated ... please now focus on the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can install it individually.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class)
public absrtact class MyHiltModule {
    @Binds
    @SomeQualifier
    abstract SomeInterface bindSomething(SomeImpl someimpl); =======> for activity scoped lifecycle
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public absrtact class MyHiltModule2 {
    @Binds
    @AnotherQualifier
    abstract SomeInterface binsAnotherThing(AnotherImpl anotherImpl); ===> for application scope lifecycle
}
```